# Is the usage of "even" in this context a mistake?

Tags: meaning-in-context, adverbs

These are the lyrics for the song "Take A Look Around" by Limp Bizkit

*"Now I know why you wanna hate me
'Cause hate is all the world has **even** seen lately"*

"I  used to love driving and repairing station wagons, **but the only one I have **even** seen lately** was in a different country"- In this one "**even**" implies to me that this person **merely saw the car** in question and **not drove it** or **made repairs** on it like in the past.

If I apply this to the lyrics it seems as if the **world** **only saw hate and not experienced etc.** in other words the scope of the influence of hate seems to be **reduced** **by** the usage of "**even**" and not emphasized as I think the band intended."Cause hate is all the world **has seen lately**" doesn't limit hate's reach to only visual experience.

**Is that correct?**

**Is the definition for "even" below the correct one?**

"even" adverb:

used to stress an extreme or highly unlikely condition or instance
*so simple even a child can do it* (Merriam-Webster).

Comment: ***even*** is increasingly used in very "loose" ways that would rarely have occurred even just a few decades ago. For example, *What do you even mean by that?* isn't remotely unusual to many younger speakers today, but I can't help thinking it's "weird".

Comment: I both of the examples you provided in your comment "even" emphasizes the sentence. "even just a few decades ago" emphasized the shortness of time and "what do you even mean by that" emphasizes that you "only have something in mind" not necessarily trying to implement your idea. "hate is all the world has even seen lately" is not emphasizing the scope of the influence of hate though. Doesn't it mean that "even" is used incorrectly?

Comment: Your understanding of how *even* is used in the song lyric is not quite right.   It does not mean *the world has only seen but not experienced hate*.  The use of *even* in the lyric merely emphasizes *all*, increasing the intensity of its *all-ness.*  From my perspective it is largely unnecessary.  I can't comprehend how all can be increased.  But as FumbleFingers says there is much latitude in how *even* is being used.

Comment: Sorry if it's confusing. Yeah - I deliberately included ***even** just a few decades ago* as a "traditionally valid" usage, to exaggerate the contrast with *What do you **even** mean by that?* (quite common today, but would almost *never* have occurred just a few decades ago).

Comment: @EllieK-Don'tsupporther: I "sorta" agree with you (that we should understand ***even*** as intensifying ***all***), but even if we discount the (very real, imho! :) possibility that younger speakers simply don't know what they're talking about, it's perfectly possible to ***orally*** deliver OP's example without ***even***, but with heavy stress on ***seen*** (as opposed to ***all***). So we *could* argue for ***even*** intensifying ***seen*** rather than ***all***. It's just more difficult *semantically* to explain what "intensified" ***seen*** might imply!

Comment: @EllieK - Don't support her So does it mean that the definition for "even" that I provided in the post is the wrong one for the context? If yes, can you provide a correct one?

Comment: @StaticBounce - Your definition is the correct one.  The debate is over which word it is modifying.  It the not too distant past it would most often modify *all*.  As the word is currently used, it could be modifying *seen*, in which case your interpretation would be the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that in the lyrics sited, "even" is superfluous and you could completely leave it out without affecting the intended meaning. My guess is that it was used to fill out the needed syllables in the song.

I don't think that it typically used to indicated a deeper context, as you questioned, other than the dictionary meaning implied. I would say that the dictionary meaning could be expanded to include use for extremely likely and extremely unlikely situations.

> "Even my grandma can use the Internet."

As others have pointed out, colloquial use of even has reached new heights and has lessened the meaning of any emphasis in certain contexts.

> "What do you even mean by that?"

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20do%20you%20even%20mean&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) showing how rapidly ***even*** has been taken up recently in a context that sounds really weird to me...

[image]

But it's all relative, and relatively speaking it's still [not at all common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%20do%20you%20even%20mean%2CWhat%20do%20you%20mean&year_start=1970&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3) to include ***even*** there...

[image]

---

TL;DR: Don't spend too long trying to work out exactly what ***even*** means. Quite often in modern texts it hardly even means anything at all. (It doesn't really make any difference whether I include it in my preceding sentence or not! :)